# Split an Array of Arrays based on key values - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, split

I am getting an array from Post after the user submits a form. The data comes back to me as an array, but inside it there are 2 more arrays and a few elements that belong to the parent array. 
How can I extract the arrays that are inside the parent array (based on their names) and add the remaining elements in a new array.

```
array (size=x)
       'parent_array_element1' => string 'value1'
       'parent_array_element2' => string 'value2' 
       'parent_array_element3' => string 'value3' 
       'parent_array_element4' => string 'value4'
       'parent_array_element5' => string 'value5'
       'parent_array_element6' => string 'value6' 
       'parent_array_element7' => string 'value7'
       'parent_array_element8' => string 'value8'
       'parent_array_element9' => string 'value9'
       'parent_array_element10' => string 'value10' 
   'internalArray1' => 
      array 
        'internalArray1_element1' => string 'value1'
        'internalArray1_element2' => string 'value2'
        'internalArray1_element3' => string 'value3'
        'internalArray1_element4' => string 'value4' 
        'internalArray1_element5' => string 'value5' 
        'internalArray1_element6' => string 'value6'
        'internalArray1_element7' => string 'value7'
    'internalArray2' => 
      array
        'internalArray2_element1' => string 'value1'
        'internalArray2_element2' => string 'value2'
        'internalArray2_element3' => string 'value3'
        'internalArray2_element4' => string 'value4'
        'internalArray2_element5' => string 'value5'
```

What I 've done so far is to get the data as a whole by doing this in my controller:

```
//Gets the parent array (Including nested arrays)
$data = $this->params()->fromPost(); 
//Gets the internaArray1
$data = $this->params()->fromPost('internalArray1'); 
//Gets the internaArray2
$data = $this->params()->fromPost('internalArray2');
```

But there is data left in the parent array, how do I get that?

Comment: Could you provide code the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: are you looking to flatten the array?

Comment: Unset in full array $full[internalArray1] and $full[internalArray3]

Comment: @splash58 Thank, you that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unset` to remove nested arrays from parent

```
//Gets the parent array (Including nested arrays)
$data = $this->params()->fromPost();

//Gets the internalArray1
$internalArray1 = $data['internalArray1'];
//Remove internalArray1 from parent
unset($data['internalArray1']);

//Gets the internalArray2
$internalArray2 = $data['internalArray2'];
//Remove internalArray2 from parent
unset($data['internalArray2']);
```

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted as mentioned above by @splash58 but I do not know how to accept a comment as answer. Therefore I accept your answer so people visiting the post in the future can clearly see it. Thank you